# mod(R/I) is an exact abelian full subcategory of mod(R)

Tags: modules, abelian-categories

This is a verification rather than a question.

So I was asked to show that if the category mod$(R/I)$ is an exact abelian full subcategory of category of mod$(R)$. For $R$ a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal of $R$.

Now  $R \rightarrow R/I$ this canonical maps ensures that mod$(R/I)$ consists of only those $R$ modules which is annihilated by $I$.

It is abelian as kernels and cokernels are $R/I$ modules and $\textbf {Coimage}(f) \cong \textbf{Im}(f)$.

Now to prove it is full subcategory and the inclusion functor is exact doesn't it suffice to state my previously mentioned comment that **mod**$(R/I)$ consists of only those $R$ modules which is annihilated by $I$.

That means $$ \textbf {Hom}_{\textbf {mod(R/I)}}(M,N) = \textbf {Hom}_{\textbf {mod(R)}}(M,N)$$

Or is there some really explicit way to prove the full and exact portion?

Comment: the exactness you can write down explicitly thanks to your observation for kernels and cokernels. and for fullness, that should indeed suffice.

Comment: Ok, thank you for verifying this fact.